# net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE Laravel sail

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laravel-sail

I've created a project with Laravel 9 and used Sail to build it.

Everything worked fine until today, I started getting `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` on some endpoints.

I've searched on Google and did not find anything about it.

Someone says that I need to disable OPCache but it is not right way.

Comment: Well... what you need is a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example